# Unified file system across Windows and Linux for type-2 hypervisor

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Is there anyway to map a Windows disk partition( c:/, d:/) to Linux (running as guest on top of Windows host Type-2 hypervisor)?

There are few solution like a shared folder in VirtualBox, however, this doesn't give a block device view of the Windows drive . I am exploring to see if the Windows drive can directly be mapped into the Linux guest, and presented as sort of psuedo device which can be mounted, and can seen as a device within Linux.

I feel it can be achieved through the Windows filter driver. Is there a clean way of doing this, from Linux's side as opposed to Windows?

Comment: What do you need to do to the raw disk device?

Comment: I'm not 100% on what your question is; or even what you really need.  I'm not sure about doing this type of thing from a VM.  I think it might be possible, in some regard to  your requirements.  I just don't know what those requirements precisely are.